# Which one is right: "......, then why couldn't IT have done?" or "................then why couldn't have IT done?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, modal-verbs

This is from BBC about space and planets [Questions about space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IC_AWX0v2Y) (see:19:37-19:43)

**"So if life could have started on Earth, then what's to say that life wouldn't have started on Mars?"**

I understood the sentence, furthermore, I like the sentence structure, and I want to use it in daily life, but I want to be able to use that structure without using **"what is to say"** and using **"could"** instead of **"would"** in the second part of the sentence in order to keep the probability or the mystery more emphasized. So, should I say:

**"So if life could have started on Earth, then why couldn't it have started on Mars?"**

or should I put **"IT"** between **"have and started"**, like so:

**"So if life could have started on Earth, then why couldn't have it started on Mars?"**

Comment: Hi, asking for text to be proof-read and errors found is off-topic here. Have you researched this? Is there a reason you think you *could* write it differently?

Comment: @Astralbee, because I want to keep the probability or the mystery - in the first part of the sentence- more emphasized. I think "would" in the second part doesn't sound in parallel with the "could have structure" in the first part of the sentence, which is perfect to emphasize the probability. I didn't understand that why did she not keep the same structure and use it the second part of the sentence?

Comment: @yunus The question in your last comment is different from the question in your post. For the question in your post, you are really asking about word order in "open" questions (sometimes called "wh-questions") that contain auxiliary verbs. That is the issue that you should research, as AB suggested. If you find explanations of the issue that don't address it well, then feel free to ask here, stating why the explanations weren't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "canonical" form (as a positive statement, and not a question) would be

> It could have started on Mars.

The question is formed by inverting the auxiliary "could" with "it".

> Could it have started on Mars?

Adding back the negation and the word "why" gives

> Why couldn't it have started on Mars?

In cases in which the subordinate clause of the auxillary verb itself contains an auxiliary you only invert with the first verb when forming a question

> It is being read by the author.

> Is it being read by the author?  and not "*Is being it read by the author?"